# Como mostrar respuestas en el postman propios de loadUserByUsername con spring scurity y jwt

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security

Estoy intentando mejorar mi forma de logearme mandando mensajes en el postman
personalizado ya sea cuando el usuario este vacio , si ingreso el usuario o contraseña incorrecto y otra validacion donde si el usuario esta vigente o suspendido

**esto es mi repositorio donde consumo mi preocedimiento almacenado:**

```
public interface AccesoLoginRepository extends JpaRepository<Login, String> 
{
    @Query(value = "{call SP_Acceso_Login(:usuario)}", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Login> acceso_login(@Param("usuario") String usuario);
}
```

**y aqui consumo el loadUserByUsername que implmento de UserDatailsService:**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private AccesoLoginRepository acceso;

  Adclic adcliente = new Adclic();

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Login login = acceso.acceso_login(username).orElseThrow(
        () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("El usuario con el" + username +
            "no existe"));
    if (username == null || username.isEmpty()) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("username is Empty");
    }
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    System.out.println("==========authorities==========");
    System.out.println(authorities);
    System.out.println("==========authorities==========");
    return new UserDetailsImpl(login);

  }
}
```

**esto es mi componente de UserDetailsImpl**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {
    private final Login login;
    // private final Aduser aduser;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(login.get_ul_pasword());
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login.getResultado();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    // paso 7 agregar esto en el jwt
    public String getResultado() {
        return login.getResultado();
    }

    public String getCodCli() {
        return login.get_codCli();
    }

    public String getCodUser() {
        return login.get_codUser();
    }

    public String getTipUsu() {
        return login.get_ul_ctipusu();
    }

    public String getNomUser() {
        return login.get_ul_nomuser();
    }

    public String getUlEstado() {
        System.out.println(login.get_ul_estado());
        return login.get_ul_estado();
    }
}
```

**lo que pasa es que el UsernameNotFoundException no se muestra en el postman
lo intente con el ResponseEntity.status pero igual no llego a la respuesta que quiero**

**muestro de como sale en el postman:**

al mnos deberia salir algo asi "Mensaje":"Logeado Exitoso"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias :D

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué versión de Spring Boot estás usando?

Comment: 2.5.4 si no mal recuerdo

Comment: @KirbyDamaso ¿Será que ya recordaste?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres modificar las respuestas que obtienes desde el servidor, esto puedes realizarlo desde el controlador "/rest" en el metodo que recibe peticiones POST al endpoint "/tokenCreated".

Lo que debes pensar es que según el codigo que proporcionaste en tu clase `UserDetailServiceImpl` el metódo `loadUserByUsername(String username)` puede o no tirar excepciones de tipo `UsernameNotFoundException`. Si el usuario existe no tirará ninguna excepción, pero si es el caso que no existe o que no se especifica entonces se tira la excepción.

Una vez sabiendo esto, puedes modificar el funcionamiento del metodo que recibe la peticion de login para que devuelva una respuesta implementando un manejo de excepciones en el cual si se tira una excepción de tipo `UsernameNotFoundException` se modifique la respuesta que se manda al cliente dependiendo del contenido de la excepción que se encontró.

Aquí tienes un posible ejemplo de como realizarlo
Controlador

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final UserDetailServiceImpl  loginService;

    @PostMapping("/tokenCreated")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> realizarLogin(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        LoginResponse respuestaLogin;
        try {
            service.loadUserByUsername(request.getUsername());
            respuestaLogin = new LoginResponse("Login Exitoso");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(respuestaLogin);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException exception) {     
            respuestaLogin = new LoginResponse(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Clase LoginRequest que se recibira en el cuerpo de la petición

```
public class LoginRequest{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public LoginRequest(){}; // constructor vacío necesario
    /* getters y setters */
    ...
}
```

Clase LoginRequest que se enviará en el cuerpo de la respuesta

```
public class LoginResponse{
    private String mensaje;
    public LoginResponse(String mensaje){ // constructor que recibe el mensaje que se enviara como respuesta
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    };
    /* getters y setters */
    ...
}
```

Recuerda adaptar el codigo a las necesidades de tu proyecto.

Comment: lo que pasa mi pro yo no hago un controlador eso lo hago desde el webSecurityConfig , es muy distinto lo que ando haciendo

Comment: En todo proyecto web de spring debe existir algún controlador o servlet, o algo parecido que reciba las peticiones y las maneje según sea el caso, si lo haces desde alguna clase de configuración de spring security (lo cual no es para nada lo ideal o no sabes explicarte) al menos incluye el código para poder ayudarte.